# Insert Schema.org properties: JQuery or DOMDocument?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, domdocument, schema.org

My Wordpress plugin inserts schema properties to the source-code of the page. So far, I used DOMDocument to accomplish this.

```
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $img->setAttribute('itemprop', 'image');
}
```

Since I'm already using JQuery in the same plugin, I thought of replacing the function with this.

```
$('img').attr('itemprop', 'image');
```

The reason why I'd prefer JQuery is this: I've noticed that invalid HTML syntax can break the DOMDocument method. As I can't expect other users of the plugin to use valid HTML only, I disabled the error reporting for that function. I don't feel comfortable doing this and the JQuery function seems to work more elegantly (in my opinion!) Also, I haven't found a way to insert properties that way into the body-tag, I was only able to add properties to tags within the body (I wonder how you do that!)

However, the JQuery function has one disadvantage - and that will finally lead to my question. I've noticed that the inserted properties will not display in the source view of Firefox or Chrome. That's probably because JQuery inserts those after the page is rendered. I can see the item properties in Firebug and the Chrome inspector.

Now.

I don't have much insight on how crawlers work, if they will/can execute Javascript. If they don't, there's no point in using JQuery for this.

What do you think, what's *better*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crawlers will not read the jQuery inserted metadata.  You need to add this content prior to sending the http response.

The DOMDocument breaking can probably be fixed by specifying the correct doctype.  In any event, a post-render javascript solution is insufficient because the metadata is invisible to search engines.

Answer (score 3):

You'll know exactly what the crawler sees by using the rich snippets testing tool:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets